# How can I prevent other agents from covering the pop-up that appears when clicking on an agent?

Tags: anylogic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pHeF.png)

As shown in the captured image above, other agents are covering the pop-up layer that appears when you click the person shape.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ykSe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMY91.png)

The name of the pop-up layer was named “group”, and the Z-axis of level 2 to which “gruop” belongs was set to “20” to expose it to the top, but it was of no use.

The pop-up layer is exposed on top and is not covered by other agents.

Answer (score 1):

The z-layer size is irrelevant in 2D animation. You need to change the "Order" level by right-clicking the group:
[image]

So move the house animation "below" the group's animation and you will be good